# How to serve https requests in Ktor programmatically

Tags: kotlin, https, ktor

To serve https requests in Ktor, their documentation states you need to set some config properties (`ktor.security.ssl`) in application.conf, such that Ktor can find the ssl certificate. However, I want to retrieve the ssl certificate from another server (via an encrypted connection).

Can I setup my Ktor server in such a way that I retrieve this certificate and enable https on server startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is still wondering about this, the way to do this is to start your Ktor server as an embedded server and supply it with your own `ApplicationEngineEnvironment` (As a reference you can use the function `io.ktor.server.engine.CommandLine.Kt`).

In this `ApplicationEngineEnvironment` you can customize the way the SSL certificate is loaded.